# ReactJS component functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Still have stupid questions about ReactJS =)
Is there any way to add public functions to React components?
I'm trying to make something like this:

```
var LoginForm = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
    },  
    render: function() {
    },
    MyFunc: function () {
    }
})
...
var login_form = LoginForm({});
React.renderComponent(login_form, document.body);
...
login_form.MyFunc (); <-- error
```

Can you explain please what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're not supposed to use a component's method outside of the component itself (or by passing it as a callback to a child component).  You should treat these as private methods.

However, you can use a feature of React called `statics` to provide functions that *are* available from outside the component.  However these should be treated like static functions of a class, and as a result they don't get access to the internals of an instance of your component (such as `this.props` or `this.state`).

Here's an example of some statics setup for a component:

```
var Component = React.createClass({
    statics: {
        // these functions are available outside the component
        renderToBody: function() {
            React.renderComponent(
                <Component />,
                document.body
            );
        }
    },

    // cannot access this function outside the component
    getHelloWorld: function() {
        return 'Hello World!';
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>{this.getHelloWorld()}</div>
        );
    }
});
```

So if we call `React.renderComponent(Component({}), elem)` then the component would render to `elem` but because of the static you could call `Component.renderToBody()` and it would render the component directly to the `<body>` element.

IE: Functions defined inside the component's `statics` object are available directly as static functions.  However you must remember that they are `static` in that they are *not* part of an instantiated component object, they are just functions you can call on the class.

The whole idea with react is that components are as self-contained as possible.  You should never need to access a component instance function directly from outside a component as what you should do instead is just change the props for the component and re-render it so that it, internally, can change.

Here's an example of that:

```
var Component = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        // always get in the habbit of using propTypes!
        message:    React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,

        show:       React.PropTypes.bool
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div style={{display: this.props.show ? 'block' : 'none'}}>
                {this.props.message}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Whereas you might have created a method `show()` on the component instead (so that you could do `component.show(true)` or `component.show(false)` to show/hide - you instead pass it as a property for the same result.

Calling `React.renderComponent(Component({message: 'foo', show: true}), elem)` will render the component visible, re-rendering with `show: false` will hide it, etc.  Same result, but with props, which is the react way.

Comment: Thank you very much Mike, you helped me a lot! Can I ask last question please? As I understanding I can mount many Components to one node? So I can itarate them? For example if I nounted 3 vicible componentts and then want to hide second.

Comment: You can only mount one component on a given html element.  However, one of the best ways to deal with multiple components is to mount a parent component and then just make everything else you need a child of that parent.  But yes you can iterate and mount multiple instances of the same component.  In react this is as simple as iterating and pushing components to an array, then rendering the array inside the `render` function of a component such as `<div>{yourArray}</div>`

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that LoginForm({}) *does not return the component*. It returns a descriptor object that will be used by React to instantiate the component later. There are two ways you can access the actual component:

- as `this` in the component methods
- by giving the component a `ref=name` prop; the actual component will be available in the creator, as this.refs.*name* by the time the creator's `componentDidMount` executes.

http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by using the result of the rendering function:

```
var login_form = React.renderComponent(LoginForm({}), document.body);
login_form.MyFunc();
login_form.setProps({loaded: true});
```

The use case for this is that you can call setProps on the root component (but only on the root).