# How to implement login-dependent paths with react-router, when the login-status is in the component-state?

Tags: javascript, authentication, reactjs, react-router, flux

I'm trying to implement the [auth-flow example](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/tree/master/examples/auth-flow) from the [react-router](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router)-repo, but I'm running into issues for my usecase, which I don't grok as a ReactJS beginner.

My login-status is based on the existence of a CSRF-cookie, so I have a method in my App which retrieves the CSRF-cookie and saves its value in state:

```
@autobind
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      csrfToken : '',
      log : {}
    }
  }

setCSRFToken() {
  this.state = { csrfToken : cookie.load('csrf') };
  this.setState({ csrfToken : this.state.csrfToken });
}

loggedIn() {
  return !!this.state.csrfToken
}
```

Since I only want to view my components when I'm logged in, I try to change the path in my routes according to *loggedIn()* with *onEnter={requireAuth}*:

```
function requireAuth(nextState, replace) {
  if (!App.loggedIn()) {
    console.log('No csrfToken found, asking for login')
    replace({
      pathname: '/login',
      state: {nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }
    })
  }
}

render((
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App} onEnter={requireAuth}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/hello" component={Hello}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>

), document.querySelector('#main'))
```

App.loggedIn() is not working though, as it's not a public function. According to  this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26201801/reactjs-component-functions), a public function in ReactJS has no access to the internal state, as intended by React's architecture, so it would not help to implement it with *static*.

I could probably go ahead and save the login-status in local storage, but I wonder if there's a different approach to solve this in ReactJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm setting login state in Store (like Flux suggests) and in routes:

```
const UserStore = require("./stores/UserStore.js");

let is_user_logged_in = !!UserStore.getToken();

UserStore.addChangeListener(() => {
    is_user_logged_in = !!UserStore.getToken();
});

function requireAuth(nextState, replaceState) {
    if (!is_user_logged_in) {
        replaceState({nextPathname: 'login'}, '');
    }
}

const routes = (
    <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
        <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
        <Route path="login" component={Login}/>
        <Route path="secret" component={Secret} onEnter={requireAuth}/>
        <Route path="*" component={NotFound}/>
    </Route>
);

module.exports = routes;
```

works great, built several apps with this :)

UserStore.js:

```
"use strict";
const AppDispatcher = require('./../dispatchers/AppDispatcher.js');
const EventEmitter = require('eventemitter3');
const assign = require('object-assign');
const store = require('store');
const Api = require('./../helpers/Api.js');
const UserActions = require('./../actions/UserActions.js');
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

const UserStore = assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {

    token: null,
    error: null,

    setError: function ({error}) {
        this.error = error;
    },

    getError: function () {
        return this.error;
    },

    setToken: function ({token}) {
        this.token = token;

        if (token !== null) {
            store.set('token', token);
        } else {
            store.remove('token');
        }
    },

    getToken: function () {
        return this.token;
    },

    emitChange: function () {
        this.emit('USER_CHANGE');
    },

    addChangeListener: function (cb) {
        this.on('USER_CHANGE', cb);
    },

    removeChangeListener: function (cb) {
        this.removeListener('USER_CHANGE', cb);
    },

});

AppDispatcher.register(function (action) {

    switch (action.actionType) {
        case 'user_login':
            Api.login({
                username: action.data.username,
                password: action.data.password,
                cb: function ({error, response}) {
                    if (error !== null) {
                        console.log('#dfd4sf424');
                        console.log(error);
                        UserActions.logout();
                    } else {
                        if (response['success'] === false) {
                            UserStore.setError({error: response['error']});
                            UserStore.emitChange();
                        } else {
                            UserStore.setError({error: null});
                            UserStore.setToken({token: response['auth-token']});
                            UserStore.emitChange();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            break;
        case 'user_logout':
            UserStore.setToken({token: null});
            UserStore.setError({error: null});
            UserStore.emitChange();
            break;
        case 'user_auto_login':
            UserStore.setToken({token: action.data.token});
            UserStore.setError({error: null});
            UserStore.emitChange();
            break;
    }
});

module.exports = UserStore;
```

Comment: Hrrm, I hoped I coud do without flux/redux for now... 

But I'll try this approach. Can you please elaborate a bit on the concept of the store or add links, so the answer is more exhaustive, before I accept it?

The redux-documentation gives a nice overview on the concept I think: http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html

The documentation on reactjs.org is pretty dry and inaccessible imho :-(

Comment: reactjs should not give such docs, because it's up to developer. It's not react thing, just simple javascript with some pattern called flux. Added my user store code to answer

Comment: Yeah, you are right - just wanted to rant about the ReactJS-docs in general I guess ;-)